# EF primitive properties not mapped even though are persisted in DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have the following class:

```
 public class MyModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; } 
    }
```

and the following Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext<MyModel>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().ToTable("MyModels");
        }
    }
```

When I am saving in the DB, I assign only some fields Timestamp, Address, Name and the rest of the fields I update them later (City, State):

```
var model = new MyModel(){Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Address = "value here", Name = "value here"};
_dbContext.MyModels.Add(model);
_dbContext.SaveChanges(); => Everything is persisted fine in DB
```

.... later on ...

```
var model = _dbContext.MyModels.Where(...);
model.State = "Value here"; //And the rest of the properties updated here
_dbContext.SaveChanges(); => Everything is updated fine in DB
```

.... and even later

```
var model = _dbContext.MyModels.Where(...);
```

=> Here only the properties that were initialized first are retrieved correctly (Timestamp, Address, Name) while the updated properties (City, State) are null even though in the DB have the correct values.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Edit:

If I reinitialize the _dbContext

```
_dbContext = new ApplicationContext()
var model = _dbContext.MyModels.Where(...);
```

in the last code snippet before querying the collection, I get the correct results. Why does this happen?

Comment: I assume this is always the same `dbContext` instance?

Comment: Nope, they are different _dbContext instances pointing to the same connection (a different instance everytime I use them).